# Prolog - Balanced tree or not

Tags: prolog, tree-balancing

I want to write a program that tells me if a tree is balanced or not. In this case balanced means same height or a height difference of 1.

This is what I've written so far but it doesn't work for the height difference of 1. Why?

```
balanced(l(_)).
balanced(b(B1, B2)):-
    height(B1,H),
    height(B2,H),
    balanced(B1),
    balanced(B2).

balanced(b(B1,B2)):-
    height(B1,H + 1),
    height(B2,H),
    balanced(B1),
    balanced(B2).

balanced(b(B1,B2)):-
    height(B1,H),
    height(B2,H + 1),
    balanced(B1),
    balanced(B2).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`H + 1` is not evaluated to the value of `H` plus one if you don't tell Prolog to do arithmetic evaluation; instead, Prolog builds a term with `+` as the functor and `H` and `1` as the arguments. (Try `H + 1 =.. L` and check the value of `L` to convince yourself of this fact.)

Do something like

```
height(B1, H1),
height(B2, H2),
abs(H1 - H2) =< 1.
```

`=<` will perform arithmetic evaluation.

Comment: If I try your suggestion my tree6(b(b(l(1), b(l(2), b(l(3),b(l(4), l(5))))),b(l(6), b(l(7), b(l(8),b(l(9), l(10))))))) is balanced according to the code, and it's not supposed to be.

Comment: @Josie, forgot a call to the `abs` function.

Comment: You also have to check the subtrees.

Comment: @starblue, who were you addressing?